# make absolute positioned element's min-height to value whichever is bigger?

Tags: html, css

I have a side menu that needs to be at least 500px in height. However it also needs to go all the way to bottom.

On screens where there is space like monitor mh100% works fine. However, on mobile if there is no other content then menu gets trimmed.

if i set fixed value then on large screen it doesn't expands to bottom all the way.

i could use two divs, parent with minh100% and child with fixed height this way parent would have a background color and would appear to make menu expand

but would like to know if there is another way that doesn't require me to clutter html for visual purposes only.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I haven't understood exactly what you are looking for, it seems like this should be pretty easy.

Edit: I missed the absolute position part of your question, but it's not much different:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<main>
    <h1>Page</h1>
    <p>Content.</p>
    <p>Content.</p>
    <p>Content.</p>
    <p>Content.</p>
    <p>Content.</p>
</main>

<style type="text/css">
  html,body {
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
  }

  nav {
    position:absolute;
    min-height:500px;
    height:100%;
    background:#ccc;
    width:30%;
  }

  main {
    width:60%;
    padding:0 5%;
    float:right;
  }
</style>
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/purnf1tw/1/)